# go get specific version

Tags: docker, go

I want to know how go get works, because when im using a libary from github (for example gorilla/mux) the documentation said to install it I should type "go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux", it strange without specific version.!

As far as i know it always use from master branch.
What happen if the owner of the library update the code? Is it gonna be deprecated or something?

Because in my case, im using docker to build the project, every time I build the image, it always do "go get"

Is there any best practice to using go get?

Comment: `go get` pulls master@HEAD. If you want more control, take a look at the new modules setup in Go 1.11, or any of the many Go dependency managers out there.

Comment: @Adrian Is there a package manager for go? like pip, composer or npm?

Comment: which version of go you were using?

Comment: @nilsocket im using 1.10.2

Comment: There are several, but *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: package versioning is added to `go` in `1.11` it's in experimental phase , if the package which you are using have .mod file, then see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-install-and-activate-module-support), to known more about module support read this [wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).

Comment: @Adrian I think the question still related, because im confusing how go get works, I actually a python and php developer, and im using package manager to install a library from outside, that’s why im asking instead of feature like “modules” is there another tools like composer or pip

Comment: I'm not saying it's not relevant, but it's off-topic for this site, for the stated reason.

Comment: @nilsocket yup still experimental phase, do you use go get to install library from outside in your go project? or you have your own way to handle this case

Comment: I believe dep is the preferred dependency manager for Go before 1.11
https://github.com/golang/dep

Comment: use the environment variable for now, and it seems `mux` doesn't depend on anything but `stdlib`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `go get library@version`. For example, `go get foo/bar@v1.2.3`